# testng / Jenkins - include name, parameterized

Tags: jenkins, testng, gherkin, qaf, testng.xml

I'm new in programming. I have a question about testng.xml and Jenkins.
I run a parameterized build in Jenkins with the following parameters:

```
install
-Dreportium-job-name=${JOB_NAME}
-Dreportium-job-number=${BUILD_NUMBER}
-Dreportium-tags=${myTag}
-DtestngXmlDir=src/main/resources/jenkins/test/scenarios/JPMTEST
-DtestngXmlFile=JPM1-testng_oekktest.xml
-Dtests=Galaxy_S9
```

My testng.xml

```
<test name="Galaxy_S9" enabled="true">

<parameter name="driver.capabilities.scriptName" value="Galaxy_S9"></parameter>
<parameter name="driver.capabilities.deviceName" value="1C5B539704037ECE"></parameter>
<parameter name="env.resources" value="src/main/resources/common;src/main/resources/android;src/main/resources/android/test" />
<parameter name="username" value="test.testuser9@test.ch" />
<parameter name="password" value="Abcd1234" />
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="@MTC-016432" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Now if I start the Jenkins build, the test starts only for "Galaxy_S9" and that is OK. All other phones don't start.

But now I search for a solution to give the jenkis an additional parameter for

```
<include name="@MTC-016432" />
```

to start a specified test.

How can I do that? I want to tell Jenkins which test to run e.g "@MTC-016432"

cheers Jean-Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting groups in config file, you can pass it through command line as below:

```
-Dgroups=@group1,@group2
```

As you are using QAF `GherkinScenarioFactory` you also utilize meta-data filter feature where you can pass `-Dinclude=<filter>` and `-Dinclude=<filter>` parameters. For [meta-data filter](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario_metadatata_filter_include_exclude_prop.html) to work you need to add `QAFMethodSelector` in config file as below:

```
<method-selectors>
    <method-selector>
        <selector-class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFMethodSelector" />
    </method-selector>
</method-selectors>
```

With meta-data filter you can pass parameter as below

```
-Dinclude={'groups':['@grp1']}
```

From qaf version 2.1.14, instead of `GherkinScenarioFactory` you can use `BDDTestFactory2` and take advantage of [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html)